# subsetting data based on four columns using if else statements

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I am new to R and having some issues with subsetting my data based on certain criteria. I have five columns (Location, Site, Species, Date, Time).

What I want to do is subset my data based on if the time of the last record is greater than one hour from the previous record of the same date, same species, same site, and same location. If any of the previous columns are not the same as the previous I want it to ignore it and move on.

As an example, this dataframe should say that the first two records are independent as all columns previous to the time column are the same and they are = or > than 60mins apart, whereas the last record is 59mins so is not independent.

```
  Location       Site     Species    Date     Time
  Twelve         2        frog       14-10    13:45
  Twelve         2        frog       14-10    14:45
  Twelve         2        frog       14-10    15:44
```

In this example, the first two lines are independent but the third line is a different species, and the line after is the same as the third but is a different location. The fifth line, all the data is the same as the previous line except it again is 59mins apart.

The results from this should return the first two lines (Both independent of each other),
the third line as it is independent of the line before and line after (As the species is different
from the line before, and different location to the line after), and then just the fourth line as it is
independent of the line before, the last line should not show on the subset of data as it is
not independent of the line before (<60mins apart).

```
  Location       Site     Species    Date     Time
  Twelve         2        frog       14-10    13:45
  Twelve         2        frog       14-10    14:45
  Twelve         2        badger     14-10    15:44
  Thirteen       2        badger     14-10    16:44
  Thirteen       2        badger     14-10    17:42
```

Comment: sorry, should have added if anyone can help with providing a solution please as I have a ton of data that i need to use a solution for

Comment: Did that help with your issue?

Comment: @ChuckP did you see my comments below?

Comment: Sorry I thought this was long dead.  Answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** EDITED tp include OP comments ***

`filter` to only independent rows.  `select` to not show interim colums

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Location, Site, Species, Date) %>% 
  mutate(difftime = as.numeric(hms::as_hms(Time) - hms::as_hms(lag(Time, 1)))/3600) %>%
  mutate(independent = case_when(
    is.na(difftime) ~ TRUE,
    difftime >= 1 ~ TRUE,
    difftime < 1  ~ FALSE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  filter(independent) %>%
  select(-difftime, -independent)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Location, Site, Species, Date [3]
  Location  Site Species Date  Time  
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <time>
1 Twelve       2 frog    14-10 13:45 
2 Twelve       2 frog    14-10 14:45 
3 Twelve       2 badger  14-10 15:44 
4 Thirteen     2 badger  14-10 16:44
```

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Location, Site, Species, Date) %>% 
  mutate(difftime = as.numeric(Time - lag(Time, 1))/3600) %>%
  mutate(independent = case_when(
        is.na(difftime) ~ TRUE,
        difftime >= 1 ~ TRUE,
        difftime < 1  ~ FALSE,
        TRUE ~ FALSE)
   )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#> # Groups:   Location, Site, Species, Date [3]
#>   Location  Site Species Date  Time   difftime independent
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <time>    <dbl> <lgl>      
#> 1 Twelve       2 frog    14-10 13:45    NA     TRUE       
#> 2 Twelve       2 frog    14-10 14:45     1     TRUE       
#> 3 Twelve       2 frog    14-10 15:44     0.983 FALSE      
#> 4 Twelve       2 badger  14-10 15:44    NA     TRUE       
#> 5 Thirteen     2 badger  14-10 16:44    NA     TRUE       
#> 6 Thirteen     2 badger  14-10 17:42     0.967 FALSE
```

adding `hms::as_hms` makes the warning message go away

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Location, Site, Species, Date) %>% 
  mutate(difftime = as.numeric(hms::as_hms(Time) - hms::as_hms(lag(Time, 1)))/3600) %>%
      mutate(independent = case_when(
        is.na(difftime) ~ TRUE,
        difftime >= 1 ~ TRUE,
        difftime < 1  ~ FALSE,
        TRUE ~ FALSE)
      )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#> # Groups:   Location, Site, Species, Date [3]
#>   Location  Site Species Date  Time   difftime independent
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <time>    <dbl> <lgl>      
#> 1 Twelve       2 frog    14-10 13:45    NA     TRUE       
#> 2 Twelve       2 frog    14-10 14:45     1     TRUE       
#> 3 Twelve       2 frog    14-10 15:44     0.983 FALSE      
#> 4 Twelve       2 badger  14-10 15:44    NA     TRUE       
#> 5 Thirteen     2 badger  14-10 16:44    NA     TRUE       
#> 6 Thirteen     2 badger  14-10 17:42     0.967 FALSE
```

Your data

```r
df <- readr::read_table2("Location       Site     Species    Date     Time
Twelve         2        frog       14-10    13:45
Twelve         2        frog       14-10    14:45
Twelve         2        frog       14-10    15:44
Twelve         2        badger     14-10    15:44
Thirteen       2        badger     14-10    16:44
Thirteen       2        badger     14-10    17:42")
```

Comment: Hi Chuck, thank you so much for your response, by subset I mean that I wanted a new df with only the rows as 'true', without the extra two columns you added. Is that possible to do? I also wondered, for me to learn, if you could explain the code to me? Because I can't see where it checks that the location is the same as the row before, or the site is the same as the row before, date and species is the same as the row before, and if so then apply the 1hr: (  is.na(difftime) ~ TRUE,
        difftime >= 1 ~ TRUE,
        difftime < 1  ~ FALSE,
        TRUE ~ FALSE

Comment: If any of the columns are not the same as the row before then it would be independent of the row before regardless of whether there's an hour between them or not.

Comment: I updated the answer.  The `group_by` statement lumps them together so anytime the location, site, species and date changes it is a new group and we start looking for independence again.  The `lag` command looks back one row to compare times with but it does so by group.

Comment: Hi Chuck, I have checked on different subsets of data and is working perfectly. Thank you for your help, you have saved me an inordinate amount of time.

Comment: Thanks if you'd check the green check mark I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Chuck, checked the answer, I did have one question, if I wanted to change it to 30mins instead of an hour do I just amend where it says 1 to 0.5? Thanks

Comment: Hi Chuck, just wondered if you had an answer to the above question?

Comment: You would change these two lines to .5 `        difftime >= .5 ~ TRUE,
        difftime < .5  ~ FALSE,
`