# Change time from 1 hour to 30 mins

Tags: r

A previous question was asked and answered for me, see here: ([subsetting data based on four columns using if else statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63119415/subsetting-data-based-on-four-columns-using-if-else-statements))

Kindly they resolved the issue but I had a follow up question, how can I change the time in the code from 1 hour to 30 mins?

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Location, Site, Species, Date) %>% 
  mutate(difftime = as.numeric(hms::as_hms(Time) - hms::as_hms(lag(Time, 1)))/3600) %>%
      mutate(independent = case_when(
        is.na(difftime) ~ TRUE,
        difftime >= 1 ~ TRUE,
        difftime < 1  ~ FALSE,
        TRUE ~ FALSE)
```

I tried many changes to the code but was unable to find a satisfactory answer!

Comment: Can you share your full/independent problem here only please.  For the links, one has to go for checking previous question and answer both.

Comment: By the way simply replacing `1` with `0.5` will do the job !! or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct subtraction of time units, use of `difftime` function from baseR is recommended where units can specifically be provided.  In the following syntax I used `unit = "mins"` to have a output in minutes, thereafter change your syntax accordingly.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Location, Site, Species, Date) %>% 
  mutate(difftime = as.numeric(difftime(hms::as_hms(Time), hms::as_hms(lag(Time, 1)) , unit = "mins"))) %>%
  mutate(independent = case_when(
    is.na(difftime) ~ TRUE,
    difftime >= 30 ~ TRUE,
    difftime < 30  ~ FALSE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE)
  )
```

data

```
df <- readr::read_table2("Location       Site     Species    Date     Time
Twelve         2        frog       14-10    13:45
Twelve         2        frog       14-10    14:45
Twelve         2        frog       14-10    15:44
Twelve         2        badger     14-10    15:44
Thirteen       2        badger     14-10    16:44
Thirteen       2        badger     14-10    17:42")
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I realised the issue with my code when I run your code. My column for time in my CSV is formatted as Number rather than time, so when I run both sets of code (30mins, 1hour) I got the same results. When I changed the column to time I got two different results. Is there a way for the function to work with my column formatted as a Number?